# SharePoint as a network drive - get document id programatically with Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have SharePoint 2013 mounted as a network drive. I am using Java to read the documents inside the document library. I need a way to get the document id that SharePoint maintains for uniquely identify each document.

Comment: How do you read the documents? Using standard Java IO (or NIO) services like `java.io.File`?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek: Yes. Using standard Java IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question so I am posting an answer.

What I first did was to enable Document ID feature for SharePoint. We need to go to `Site Settings` and under `Site Collection Administration` > `Site collection features`, we need to activate Document Id service. A scheduled job generally assigns document ids to all document existing in SharePoint.

Next we can use the endpoint `/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath)/ListItemAllFields` to get the document id via SharePoint REST API.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the standard Java IO to read the documents, there is no way to get the SharePoint ID of such document - Java does not know about SharePoint, the documents are just plain files from Java's point of view.

If you want to use SharePoint metadata, you need to use SharePoint API. See the [SharePoint 2013 REST Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx), or look for a 3rd party library, such as e.g. [JShare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/index.html).